# JSON Cache Header on Browser doesn't work

Tags: php, httpresponse, http-caching

I make a request to a php file and I took back these headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: max-age=360000, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 19 Jul 2018 07:08:20 GMT
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 2040 05:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

I'm using these headers to php file

```
header('Cache-Control: max-age=360000, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 2040 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

But every time I refresh the page... It's not cached... It always ask server for the response.

Any ideas? I want to be cached until expire date

Comment: Checking the headers is usually done via dev tools which while open will prevent caching from happening unless you force enable caching.

Comment: "Disable cache" is unchecked

Comment: Try adding an [ETag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `Pragma: no-cache` might be a problem, remove that header

By documentation

> The Pragma: no-cache header field is an HTTP/1.0 header intended for
>   use in requests. It is a means for the browser to tell the server and
>   any intermediate caches that it wants a fresh version of the resource,
>   not for the server to tell the browser not to cache the resource. Some
>   user agents do pay attention to this header in responses, but the
>   HTTP/1.1 RFC specifically warns against relying on this behaviour.

Comment: @Michalis do you use Chrome dev tools?

Comment: Yes... and "Disable cache" is unchecked

Comment: @Michalis can you show us how Request headers look in dev tools?

Comment: Printscreen of which page?

Comment: @Michalis https://www.mkyong.com/computer-tips/how-to-view-http-headers-in-google-chrome/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176305/discussion-between-mleko-and-michalis).